# Changing SH Directory

Tags: command-line, bash, python

I want to have a main launcher that executes a python program

The directory is `/Downloads/Test/`

```
#!/bin/bash/
python Test.py
```

I want to be able to run the file in the terminal, without the following error:

```
Failed to execute child process "/home/user/Downloads/Test/run" (Not a directory)
```

The default directory is in `/home` and I can only run `sh` there.

Comment: I am not sure I understand: *what* directory is `/Downloads/Test/`, and why are you using a script to run another script?

Comment: Is the `/` at the end of the shebang a typo in the post?

Comment: the `/` could be the problem, and also what do you mean with "only `sh`"? can you not run `bash`?

Comment: That is a sloppy way of running python scripts. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587877/run-a-python-script-in-terminal-without-the-python-command

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the directory where you have placed the python file and check the following parameters, If you have not already tried with this.

Make sure the first line of your file has #!/usr/bin/env python.

Make it executable -

```
chmod +x <filename>.py
```

And run it as

```
./<filename>.py
```